# Data file handling

Tags: python

In this program how should I store the the output of `a=1+1` in txt file? But `write()` argument must be `str`, not `int`

```
a = 1+1
w = open('r.txt','w')
w.write(a)
```

Comment: So simply ```w.write(str(a))```. Check the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str

Comment: As @Sujay said, but remember always to `w.close()` before exiting, to be sure that the bytes you passed to `w.write(bytes)` method are written before exiting.

Comment: please try to do some research before asking questions. This isn't anything new - you can easily find a solution on the web.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply convert the sum to a string using the built-in `str` function.

```
a = 1+1
w = open('r.txt','w')
w.write(str(a))
```

References

- [Built - in function `str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Also, it is better to open files with the `with open....` because the file is guaranteed to close when the `with` block ends.

```
a = 1+1
with open('r.txt','a') as w:
    w.write(str(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `print()` with `file` argument, but of course using `file.write()` is more readable.

```
with open("r.txt", "w") as w:
    print(1 + 1, file=w)
```

Comment: I'd argue that `print(1 + 1, file=w)` is more readable than `w.write(str(1 + 1))` with the ugly explicit string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `str`.

You could also try with `with open`:

```
a = 1 + 1
with open('r.txt', 'w') as w:
    w.write(str(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the code.Its shows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/projects/test_celery/test.py", line 3, in <module>
  w.write(a)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Obviously,you should trans the int byte to str,then you can write into a txt file.

```
a = 1 + 1
with open('r.txt', 'w') as w:
   w.write(str(a))
```

By the way,remember always to w.close() before exiting and 'with open() as w' can do the job.

Comment: how is your answer different than the rest?

Comment: My answer is just the same as the others.I just want to show@Kunal Telangi how to read the Traceback and to solve the issue.